# How can we run the diagrams.net source code locally

Tags: javascript, draw.io

I want to run the draw.io that is diagrams.net source code locally in my system other than the way of download the desktop app Basically I download the source code from this link

https://github.com/jgraph/drawio

I need to run this web app in my localhost please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this that are detailed in the drawio repo. Have you explored those options yet? Essentially, you can run the code from github by forking the code into your own github repo, or you can download the code and checking it into your github repo (basically the same thing) and then hosting the master branch from github pages. The URL for the application is a little different /pages/repo/src/main/webapp/index.html. Or, you can take a look at the jgraph/docker-drawio repo. There are a lot of different ways to run the docker images. https://github.com/jgraph/docker-drawio

Answer (score 0):

I am using draw.io locally, it runs inside a Tomcat web server. Just drop the war file in the webapps dir and you are ready to go!  You can download the war file from the releases on their github - https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/releases
bye
Marco